# Clearing ActiveX dropdown boxes Error 438

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that populates two ActiveX drop down menus. I have a reset button what when pressed runs a macro that populated the value field of the drop down menus. I have included the macro that is triggered when the reset button is pressed below.

```
Sub UnhideAll()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Control Panel").Shapes.Range(Array("ComboBox1")).ControlFormat.Value = "Choosing Region"
    Worksheets("Control Panel").Shapes.Range(Array("ComboBox2")).ControlFormat.Value = "Choosing Office"
    Worksheets("Global").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Global").Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I keep getting Run time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: try: Worksheets("Control Panel").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value = "Choosing Region"

Comment: @EvR that will work, but it's still late-bound code that's prone to error 438. Best work with declared types and avoid unnecessary late binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after `Worksheets(...)` is late-bound, because `Worksheets` yields an `Object`: you're essentially coding blindfolded. Help the compiler by telling it what interface you mean to work with - in this case, `Worksheet`:

```
Dim ctrlPanelSheet As Worksheet
Set ctrlPanelSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Panel")
```

Now member calls against `ctrlPanelSheet` will be compile-time validated, and you'll get IntelliSense/member-completion on its member calls.

That said, `ControlFormat` is a member of the [`Shape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.controlformat) class, but you're invoking it against a `ShapeRange` object. When you make a [late-bound] member call against an object, for a member that doesn't exist on that object, you get run-time error 438.

But you don't need a `ShapeRange` when you're only working with a single control...

```
ctrlPanelSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.Value = "..."
```

Now, doing that will raise a *type mismatch* error - `ComboBox1` looks much more like an ActiveX control than a *form control* (that would default to something like `Drop Down 1`) - you want to get that `MSForms.ComboBox` object, and you can get it from the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection:

```
Dim oleBox1 As OLEObject
Set oleBox1 = ctrlPanelSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
```

The OLEObject is wrapping your `MSForms.ComboBox` control:

```
Dim box1 As MSForms.ComboBox
Set box1 = oleBox1.Object
```

And now that you have a `MSForms.ComboBox` object, you can do everything you could normally do with a `MSForms.ComboBox` object - all with compile-time validation:

```
box1.Value = "Test"
```